# PHP content caching for javascript and css

Tags: php, javascript, css, caching

I have a unique problem, which is proving difficult to solve using google. I am consolidating all of my javascript and css into separate php files, which use require_once() to pull the contents of the files in. The javascript file looks something like this:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/javascript');
require_once('jquery.form.js');
require_once('jquery.jqtransform.js');
require_once('jquery.validate.js');
?>
```

My specific problem is that web browsers will 'see' that this is a dynamic page, because of the php file extension, and then request the content anew each time a page on the site is loaded. What I am trying to do is **get the time of last request from the browser**, and then **check each file modification time** to see if I really do need to send the file contents again. It is proving difficult to find the time of last request by the user. Also, I have not yet started to tackle the problem of finding the last modified date of the files that are included, so if there is information regarding **finding the file details of a file on the server**, that would also be appreciated.

Just to be clear, the reason I am doing this is because (I think) it takes advantage of the gzip compression better than individually gzipped files.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Minify - http://code.google.com/p/minify/ - is a library designed to do what is required here - concatenate the files and send the appropriate headers, also trimming down the contents, and quite possibly gzipping them, while caching the results on disk.

Comment: I thought about just concatenating and minifying, but I would like to retain some dynamic control over the contents, especially when I'm still developing the site and changing my code constantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your premise is incorrect. Browsers don't "see" the PHP file extension and decide not to cache things. See http://www.enhanceie.com/redir/?id=httpperf for information on how browsers really work.

You should set an ETAG on your response, and then you can simply check the If-None-Match request header and return a 304 if the content is unchanged.

Comment: +1. Though easier still would be to avoid serving scripts and stylesheets through PHP. There's no real advantage to it.

Comment: @bobince: Sure there is. Fewer HTTP requests.

Comment: Mark has it right. I want to take advantage of the compression and fewer http requests

Comment: JS-min (http://github.com/rgrove/jsmin-php) can be set to concatenate, zip and store the final version on disk, outputting it as required, and rebuilding the cache if required.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a series of posts about this issue specifically. See [Supercharging Javascript in PHP](http://www.cforcoding.com/2009/05/supercharging-javascript.html) and [Supercharging CSS in PHP](http://www.cforcoding.com/2009/05/supercharging-css-in-php.html). These cover:

- Combining files;
- Gzipping best practices;
- Caching best practices; and
- Versioning output.

Comment: I started using that solution but when I found http://code.google.com/p/minify/ I moved away from it. While this is a great solution to get started, minify is far better in terms of ease of use and implementation not to mention there are a lot of features such as grouping ect.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers don't determine if a page or a file is dynamic or static by its extension. Its headers do. Just set the proper headers so the browser knows it can cache the results.

Also, ditch the closing `?>`. It's not required and is bad practice.

Comment: Unless you embed big parts of HTML, or whatever, you don't. If you include a file which has a space after the closing tag it can lead to some annoying "headers already sent" errors.

Comment: "For files that contain only PHP code, the closing tag ("?>") is never permitted. It is not required by PHP, and omitting it´ prevents the accidental injection of trailing white space into the response. "
Source: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/coding-standard.php-file-formatting.html

Comment: I disagree with ?> being bad practice. Though I agree with your answer to the OPs question.  I think it's far cleaner to explicitly delineate your PHP code, even if it can be done implicitly.

Comment: ?> is NOT REQUIRED however I also 100% dissagree in calling it bad.  IT will not speed up your page at all by not using it.  And as for whitespace slipping in, I haven't had that problem yet in 5-6 years

Comment: @Myles: There's nothing to delineate if it's 100% PHP.

Comment: I consider it bad practice if the file is 100% PHP. As for it not happening to you in the last couple of years I can understand that with your own code. But when using someones else library this error can slip in rather easily. It's just a pain in the ass kind of bug to find.

Answer (score 0):

Alister Bulman just mentioned a neat library solution for this problem but placed it as a comment. I'm repeating his comment as an answer since I found it valuable:

> Minify - code.google.com/p/minify - is a library designed to do what
>   is required here - concatenate the files and send the appropriate
>   headers, also trimming down the contents, and quite possibly gzipping
>   them, while caching the results on disk. –  Alister Bulman Jan 10 '10
>   at 10:44

Answer (score -1):

You can enable auto-gzipping of files using apache mod_deflate.

You can also use apache mod_rewrite to refer to these files in the html as js files and redirect the request to the php files, avoiding your server caching issues.

Something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*).js $1.php
```

Put this code in a .htaccess file in your directory.

Comment: The actual problem is nothing to do with the file extension, which is an opaque part of the URL browsers don't care about. It's the cache-control/expires/etag headers that matter.